# How to get every Monday out of a Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I need some help to understand a certain line in a code. The code takes the turnovers of every Monday in the year 2010 and at the last line in summarizes all the turnovers to one.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING (DATUM) = 1 THEN 'Gesamtumsatz'
        ELSE CAST (DATUM AS VARCHAR (40))
    END AS MONTAGSDATEN,
    AVG (VERKAUFSWERT * VERKAUFSMENGE) as UMSATZ
FROM Data_Star_Awesome.dbo.VERKAUFSFAKTEN vk
    INNER JOIN DIMDATUM dimD on vk.DATUMID=dimD.DATUMID
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,0, DATUM)%7=0 
    AND JAHR = 2010
GROUP BY ROLLUP (DATUM)
```

The problematic line I don't understand is the following:

`WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,0, DATUM)%7=0`

What I know is that it takes the days out of the date variable but I don't get the `%7=0` part. The `DATEDIFF` function should give back all the days. Are these days saved in the `%` the placeholder? And how does it get all the Mondays by using the `7=0`?

It would be great if someone could help me out.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The `%` is the mod operator.

Answer (score 1):

[Modulo or %](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) operator is the same as in a lot of programming languages. It returns the remainder after the division.

The [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function takes two dates and returns the difference in a specified datepart, which in your query is the days represented by `dd`.

Also `0` as date converts to 1/1/1900 which happens to be a [Monday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_1900). So your query is calculating the days between 1/1/1900 and the `DATUM` field in days and if its Mod is 0 then `DATUM` is Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply say:

```
datename(weekday,<datetime-value>)
```

Which will return 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', etc. The problem with this approach is that the returned value is *localized*. If the SQL server's language is changed, your test for 'Monday' will fail.

This expression will always work:

```
( @@datefirst + ( datepart(weekday,today) - 1 ) ) % 7
```

It evaluates to 1-7, where Monday is always 1 and Sunday is always 7, regardless of culture/language settings or the current value of `@@datefirst`, as set by `set datefirst`.

We can then convert this into this discriminant function, yielding 1 or 0 to indicate whether or not the date is Monday:

```
case ( @@datefirst + ( datepart(weekday,today) - 1 ) ) % 7 when 1 then 1 else 0 end
```